# JAVA rat in a maze DFS using stack and no node

Tags: java, search, depth-first-search, maze

I am a student and studying JAVA.
I did write my code for DFS (Rat in a maze) and I need to use stack. I don't want Node class and my maze is just final. [0][0] is start and [5][5] is exit which has 'e'.

So, here's my code but if I run this code, there is a reputation between (1, 3), (2, 1).
why this code failed?

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class MazeSearch {

public static final int N = 6;
boolean[][] isVisited = new boolean[N][N];

public static int[][] maze = {
        {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 'e'},               
};



public static void main(String[] args) {    
    
    if (dfs(maze, 0, 0))
        System.out.println("Success!");
    else
        System.out.println("Failed!");
    
}

public static boolean isValid(int m[][], int x, int y) {
    
    if (x< 0 || y<0 || x>= N || y>= N)
        return false;
    else
        return (m[y][x] == 0 || m[y][x] == 2);
        
    
}

public static boolean dfs(int m[][], int x, int y) {        
    
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    
    stack.push(x);
    stack.push(y);
    
    while(!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        int curx = stack.pop();
        int cury = stack.pop();
        
        System.out.printf("(" + curx + " " + cury + ")" + " -> ");
        
        if (m[cury][curx] == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("dfs searching complete!");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            m[cury][curx] = ',';
            
            if (isValid(m, curx, cury-1)) {
                stack.push(curx);
                stack.push(cury-1);
            }
            else if (isValid(m, curx, cury+1)) {
                stack.push(curx);
                stack.push(cury+1);
            }
            else if (isValid(m, curx-1, cury)) {
                stack.push(curx-1);
                stack.push(cury);
            }
            else if (isValid(m, curx+1, cury)) {
                stack.push(curx+1);
                stack.push(cury);
            }
            System.out.printf("content of stack (now): (%d, %d)\n", curx, cury);
        }
        
    }
    
    return false;
    }

}
```

EDIT: Now I repair some things and it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

1. Stacks work *Last-In-First-Out* (LIFO), so, because you are using the same stack for both `x` and `y` coordinates, note that `pop`ing should be the opposite of `push`ing in this case, ie if you `push` the `x` coordinate first and then the `y` then `y` is expected to be on top, so you should `pop` the `y` coordinate first and then the `x`.
2. You push only one neighbouring grid cell into the stack for each visited grid cell. But each grid cell has 4 neighbours, not 1. So you should check all neighbours for each visit, which means converting this:

   ```
   if (isValid(m, curx, cury-1)) {
       stack.push(curx);
       stack.push(cury-1);
   }
   else if (isValid(m, curx, cury+1)) {
       stack.push(curx);
       stack.push(cury+1);
   }
   else if (isValid(m, curx-1, cury)) {
       stack.push(curx-1);
       stack.push(cury);
   }
   else if (isValid(m, curx+1, cury)) {
       stack.push(curx+1);
       stack.push(cury);
   }
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   if (isValid(m, curx, cury-1)) {
       stack.push(curx);
       stack.push(cury-1);
   }
   if (isValid(m, curx, cury+1)) {
       stack.push(curx);
       stack.push(cury+1);
   }
   if (isValid(m, curx-1, cury)) {
       stack.push(curx-1);
       stack.push(cury);
   }
   if (isValid(m, curx+1, cury)) {
       stack.push(curx+1);
       stack.push(cury);
   }
   ```

   (basically removing the `else`s).
3. You don't use the `isVisited` array. For each grid cell you visit, you can set the corresponding location to `true` and use this information in `isValid` logic, so as to return `false` from it if the given cell is already visited.

Summarizing the notes, follows example code:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class MazeSearch {

    public static final int N = 6;
    private static boolean[][] isVisited = new boolean[N][N];

    public static char[][] maze = {
        {'0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'},
        {'0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1'},
        {'1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1'},
        {'1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1'},
        {'1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'e'}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (dfs(maze, 0, 0)) {
            System.out.println("Success!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed!");
        }

    }

    public static boolean isValid(char m[][], int x, int y) {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= N || y >= N)
            return false;
        if (isVisited[y][x])
            return false;
        return (m[y][x] == '0' || m[y][x] == '2');
    }

    public static boolean dfs(char m[][], int x, int y) {

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();

        stack.push(x);
        stack.push(y);

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            //Changed the pop sequence!
            int cury = stack.pop();
            int curx = stack.pop();

            System.out.println("Visiting [" + cury + ", " + curx + "]...");

            if (m[cury][curx] == '2') {
                System.out.println("dfs searching complete!");
                return true;
            } else {
                m[cury][curx] = ',';
                isVisited[cury][curx] = true;

                if (isValid(m, curx, cury - 1)) {
                    stack.push(curx);
                    stack.push(cury - 1);
                }
                if (isValid(m, curx, cury + 1)) {
                    stack.push(curx);
                    stack.push(cury + 1);
                }
                if (isValid(m, curx - 1, cury)) {
                    stack.push(curx - 1);
                    stack.push(cury);
                }
                if (isValid(m, curx + 1, cury)) {
                    stack.push(curx + 1);
                    stack.push(cury);
                }
                //System.out.printf("content of stack (now): (%d, %d)\n", curx, cury);
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Try changing a character from `'0'` to `'2'` (in the maze) and you will see the *Success* message (because you found it). Otherwise you will see in the console that all indices are visited, but because no `'2'` will be found then you will see *Failure* message as expected.

Comment: thx for the answer. Now I realized that I missed the stack popping order and 4 if questions need to push more neighbor cell. At last, I didn't use isVisited array. Thank you. Have a nice day.

Comment: No problem @nojob. Have a nice day too.